# Has anyone found a solution to add an appointment booking element in CiviCRM

Tags: repeating-events

We would like our users to be able to book a time slot with our Support team - I was thinking of using Microsoft Booking but am not sure if I can redirect to Civi to confirm.   Is anyone using anything different?  I there a way to do this in CiviCrm?  I am working for a Charity and am not very techinical so would really apprecaite some advice.  Thanks

Comment: i don't know of such but for someone trying to do a DIY solution for a few specific times this might be of help https://civicrm.org/extensions/availability

Comment: There is also this extension but you have to set the resources up for this to work. https://civicrm.org/extensions/civibooking - but a time slot with a Support Team can be a 'resource'

Comment: If you are using WP you can try Ninja Forms. I know that they have an appointment option with their Advanced Date Picker Add-on. Ninja Forms has some level of integration with Civi. I have not done anything with the Civi integration so I am not sure what can be accomplished there.

Answer (score 2):

A solution I've seen used in the past uses CiviCRM activities for support slots/ appointments , these are then exposed/ updated via views and webforms. So this is a Drupal specific solution. And, warning, it's admin heavy.

Create Activity type "Appointment"
And either extend the activity status list to include a "booked" option, or add a custom field of availability options "available", "booked".

Using CiviCRM's import options you can upload a list of available appointments a week, month in advance

Added by contact= staff member/ team the appointment is with
Activity status= scheduled/ available
date/ time/ duration etc

You can then build a (calendar?) view of upcoming, scheduled "appointment" activities.
And a webform for members of the public to use to update the underlying activity
change status to "booked", add contact details of person making the booking as the "with contact" on the activity.

Answer (score 1):

Would you use an activity assigned to the support team? There are ways to create forms that generate activities

Comment: I think the issue is how to make time slots show as available or taken .. oh which reminds me.

Comment: you're right, it seems like a calendly-like option